# Почему при вызове функции декоратора в JS часть скрипта пропускается?

Tags: javascript, функции

Есть код :

```
    function slow(x) {
        // здесь могут быть ресурсоёмкие вычисления
        console.log(`Called with ${x}`);
        return x;
    }

    function cachingDecorator(func) {
        let cache = new Map(); // ->?
        console.log('hello from decorator');
        return function(x) {
            if (cache.has(x)) {    // если кеш содержит такой x,
                return cache.get(x); // читаем из него результат
            }

            let result = func(x); // иначе, вызываем функцию

            cache.set(x, result); // и кешируем (запоминаем) результат
            return result;
        };
    }

    slow = cachingDecorator(slow);

    console.log( slow(1) ); // slow(1) кешируем
    console.log( "Again: " + slow(1) ); // возвращаем из кеша

    console.log( slow(2) ); // slow(2) кешируем
    console.log( "Again: " + slow(2) ); // возвращаем из кеша
```

Вопрос по строке  'let cache = new Map();' Она вызывается только один раз в момент передачи ссылки функции на ссылку декоратор с вызовом функции. Во время исполнения в строках с console.log код сразу прыгает на строчку return игнорируя все выше, хотя если идти построчно - то при каждом заходе должен образовываться новый экземпляр Map. Вместо этого происходит обращение к существующему Map, и я не понимаю где он находиться, и почему пропускается часть скрипта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `cachingDecorator` вызывается один раз. Потом несколько раз вызывается анонимная функция, которую вернула функция `cachingDecorator`, и которая сохранена в переменной `slow`.

Строки

```
    let cache = new Map(); // ->?
    console.log('hello from decorator');
```

принадлежат `cachingDecorator`, но не возвращаемой анонимной функции. Поэтому они не выполняются при вызовах `slow(...)`.

`Map` находится в замыкании, созданном вокруг анонимной функции, сохраненной в переменной `slow`.

Comment: понял возвращается вот это ``` return function(x) {
        if (cache.has(x)) {    // если кеш содержит такой x,
            return cache.get(x); // читаем из него результат
        }

        let result = func(x); // иначе, вызываем функцию

        cache.set(x, result); // и кешируем (запоминаем) результат
        return result;
    };```  и с ней происходит манипуляции. Благодарю

Comment: @ТимурКазаков Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.